# How to pass parameter to Dataset for query using c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to change SQL statement in DataSet for adding where query

```
where LogTime between @parameter1 and @parameter2
```

how can I pass parameter `DateStr` and `DateEnd` to `@parameter1` and `@parameter2`

from c# method

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
```

I guess We should Using `DataTable1TableAdapter` from `DataSet1`

Is any suggested way to Implement it ?

We got these query in `DataTable1TableAdapter` already

```
SELECT IPassLog.ParkID, ParkInfo.ParkName, IPassLog.UserID, IPassLog.LogTime, IPassLog.LogInTime, IPassLog.InitBalance,
                IPassLog.TranAmount, IPassLog.TranBalance, IPassLog.CheckDone, IPassLog.TranSN, IPassLog.PackName, IPassLog.ResultName, IPassLog.SettlementDate,
                IPass_Result_Hex.Result_Desc, IPass_ErrorCode.Explanation
                FROM IPassLog INNER JOIN ParkInfo ON IPassLog.ParkID = ParkInfo.ParkID
                FULL JOIN IPass_Result_Hex ON IPassLog.VerifyResult = IPass_Result_Hex.Result_Hex FULL JOIN IPass_ErrorCode ON IPassLog.VerifyFlag = IPass_ErrorCode.Code;
```

and I want add where statement into these query

Comment: You need to build [parameterized TableAdapter query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the post : [Tutorial 1: Creating a Data Access Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx) which talks about how to deal with parameter in table adapter query. it also provide code example for the same.

---

if you can to pass parameter to your query then create parameter like this

```
  SqlParameter param= new SqlParameter();
   param.ParameterName = "@parameter1";// Defining Name
   param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int; // Defining DataType
   param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; // Setting the direction 
   param.Value = inputvalue;
```

and add created parameter to your command object

```
 // Adding Parameter instances to sqlcommand
   comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: TableAdapter can't parse these parameter in query mode

Comment: @yihanghwang - you can follow this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx same updated in my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1(v=vs.110).aspx) class's constructor that accept SqlCommand as parameter. So that you can pass the parameterized command to this class to create the instance of SqlDataAdapter 
I prefer you to use like thi:

```
string connectionString = "your connection string here";
string query = "select blah, foo from mytable where LogTime >= @parameter1 and LogTime<= @parameter2";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, new SqlConnection(connectionString)))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("parameter1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateInput1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("parameter2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateInput2;
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna DataSet to control all SQL query ,because i will extend DataSet to Crystal Report